# Writing partial differential equation like u_t=u_xx

Tags: equations

I have a problem writing the heat equation in latex. I would like to write it by starting with \begin{equation} and ending with \end{equation}. I tried doing the following:

```
\begin{equation}
\{$u_t(x,t)=u_{xx}(x,t)$} wherex $\epsilon$ ${\rm I\!R}$\  and $t>0$  
\end{equation}
```

The answer I got was this:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `',
               but the package provides `esdiff'.
```

and

```
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   u
l.51 \{$u
         _t(x,t)=u_{xx}(x,t)$$} where x $\epsilon$ ${\rm I\!R}$\  and $t>0$
?
```

Does anyone know how to write the heat equation in latex and have the text on the same line?
David

Comment: I'll take a guess that the equation environment puts you into math mode. Take away the dollar signs, and use \text{}.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried doing what you wrote, and it gave an "output", but not with u and subscript t (the derivative of u with respect to t). When I did this: \[ u_{t}(x,t) = u_{xx}(x,t) \] I got the equation I wanted, but I would like to start with \begin{equation} so that it would be possible to have text on the same line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you maybe looking for the following?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \text macro
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for \mathbb macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\{ u_t(x,t)=u_{xx}(x,t)\}, \text{ where $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t>0$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, might you be looking for the following?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \text macro
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for \mathbb macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
u_t(x,t)=u_{xx}(x,t), \text{ where $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t>0$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `x \in \mathbb{R}` I would guess:-)

Comment: Yes, that is the way I would like to write the equation. It worked perfectly in my latex file. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I get it now: the `\epsilon` was standing in for `\in`. I've added a second screenshot to raise this possibility.

Answer (score 5):

Please always provide complete small documents that reproduce the error, not just fragments.

`equation` puts you in math mode so you should not use `$` to re-start math mode inside that.

Do not use `\rm` in latex (it is just for compatibility with the previous version, LaTeX2.09, which has not been released since 1992)

Don't use `I\!R` for a double struck R use `\mathbb{R}` don't use `\epsilon` for set membership.

```
\begin{equation}
u_t(x,t)=u_{xx}(x,t) \text{ where } x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and }  t>0  
\end{equation}
```

The package error I would guess you did

```
\input{esdiff.sty}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{esdiff}
```

Comment: perhaps better semantically to use `\qquad\text{where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t>0$}`. I've added a `\qquad` as well to separate them better.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I got the equations right (your text was a bit confusing) but here is a working (and slightly corrected in terms of coding) version

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
u_{t}\left(x,t\right)=u_{xx}\left(x,t\right) \text{where}~\epsilon = \mathrm{I!R}~\text{and}~t>0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no reason to add `\left` `\right` here.

Comment: Also `~` is the wrong tool in math mode.